# C# Console Application: Catching Some Cases of White Spaces

Tags: c#, string, split, space

I have a C# console application which parses a .txt file. The txt file has 4 values on each line. So here are a couple of samples:

```
c:\ecpg\myfolder\no_space.cfm           20160803   01:09:54   1574

c:\ecpg\myfolder\file with space.cfm           20160803   01:09:54   1574

c:\myfolder\.project                                             20170221   07:54:10   265
```

I am using the following to split based on white spaces in each row:

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
 {
    string[] parts = line.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
 }
```

Problem is that, in case of row 2, there is a space in the file name and so that's failing the parsing because now I have 5 values instead of 4. How can I prevent this? Maybe some way to detect if there is a . (dot) soon after the space?

Thank you!

Comment: You haven't defined a delimiting character for the first parameter of the split function, should be something like "new [] { ' ' }". That said, it looks like those have multiple spaces or tabs and you should handle that more appropriately.

Comment: I think char[0] is the delimiting and its working fine? I copied that from StackOverflow. Thanks.

Comment: You should understand what you copy from StackOverflow. I'm suggesting you use two or more spaces or possible "\t" as your delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex to `split` your `string`, it will give you better output. Please check my code:

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] parts = Regex.Split(line, @"(\s+\s+)");
}
```

Also I've written it in [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f8iNkQ) you can check this.

EDIT: I've edited the code and it will cover all of your scenario. [New Solution Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qYG3Mc)

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string partOne = Regex.Match(line, @"[a-z](.*)[a-z]").Value;
    //string[] parts = Regex.Split(line.Replace(partOne, ""), @"(\s+)");
    string[] parts;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(partOne))
    {
        parts = Regex.Split(line.Replace(partOne, ""), @"(\s+)");
    }
    else
    {
        parts = Regex.Split(line, @"(\s+)");
    }
}
```

Final Code:

```
List<string> parts = new List<string>();
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    parts = new List<string>();
    //string partOne = Regex.Match(line, @"[A-Za-z](.*)[A-Za-z]").Value;
    //Update Regex for handle numeric value in part one.
    string partOne = Regex.Match(line, @"[A-Za-z](.*)([A-Za-z]|([A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]))(.*?)\s").Value.Trim();
    parts.Add(partOne);
    string[] fianlParts;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(partOne))
    {
        fianlParts = Regex.Split(line.Replace(partOne, ""), @"(\s+)");
    }
    else
    {
        fianlParts = Regex.Split(line, @"(\s+)");
    }

    foreach (string part in fianlParts)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(part.Trim()))
        {
            parts.Add(part);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(parts[0] + " " + parts[1] + " " + parts[2] + " " + parts[3]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me give this a try..so small code! Good.

Comment: Getting error. Now I have 9 elements in the parts variable. I need only 4. Thanks

Comment: This is the way to go. +1.

Comment: Try the DotNetFiddle that @csharpbd provided.

Comment: How many space you have in your separator? I've written it for 2 space, if there are more just add `\s+` for one space.

Comment: Spaces are variable--they are coming in an email generated by a server processor.

Comment: spaces per email--they could change! c:\ecpg\BL_Publish_Staging_CFCS_PSC_Outage_Notification_16\add_service.cfm           20160803   01:09:54   1574

Comment: New code: On this: string[] parts = Regex.Split(line.Replace(partOne, ""), @"(\s+)"); //error: string cannot be zero

Comment: For which input?

Comment: partOne is empty

Comment: Your fiddler does work but my code does not. I have added a 3rd row for a special case of .project file. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I've checked 3rd one in fiddler. It's working but why not in your code. I'm confused. Can it give any error?

Comment: You are right, the .project also works in your fiddler. I think it's the way I am referencing the values in my subsequent code...let me check...

Comment: The way my code references values: Console.WriteLine(parts[0] + " " + parts[1] + " " + parts[2] + " " + parts[3]);

Comment: So, as per my above comment, I only need 4 values. Your fiddler works but there can be 7 values--including some empty ones. I think the variable numbers of white spaces the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137796/discussion-between-meengla-and-csharpbd).

Comment: All working except this line: c:\ecpg\BL_Publish_Staging_CFCS_AP_COA_16\COA\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2         20150616   03:56:18   18028  ;//note, .woff2 causes one more item in the finalParts variable while .woff is fine?

Comment: @Meengla I am little bit busy now, will back soon.

Comment: No problem. Thanks. I think the problem is the numeric value in .Woff2 extension which your RegEx is not catching right now.

Comment: @Meengla, I've updated the answer. Please check commented code in **Final Code** block. And replace new Regex line in your project. It will work.

Comment: "koushik.butterfly@live.com" this is my Skype address, If you want you can knock me.

Comment: Thank you too..... I'm so happy to hear that it help you. If you wish you can contact me on my Skype.

Answer (score 1):

This method is manual but works. It supports filenames with any number of spaces.
It works by locating spaces from the end of the string, retrieving three fields in the loop and finally the filename. There's plenty of room for optimalization here if you're parsing large files.

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] parts = new string[4];

    int n = -1;
    for (int idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++)
    {
        n = line.LastIndexOf(' ');
        parts[3-idx] = line.Substring(n + 1);
        line = line.Substring(0, n).TrimEnd();
    }

    parts[0] = line; // filename
}
```

If one or more of the fields are missing you can do simple pattern checks. In your file the first parameter is the filename, the second an 8-digit date, the third the time of day and the fourth (probably) the file size. In this case this code should be more robust (I didn't try compiling it so it might contain typos):

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] parts = new string[4];

    int n = -1;
    for (int idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++)
    {
        n = line.LastIndexOf(' ');
        if (n == -1 || n == 0) break;
        string part = line.Substring(n + 1);
        if (part.IndexOf(':') > 0) parts[2] = part;
        else if (part.Length == 8) parts[1] = part;
        else parts[3] = part; // assuming you don't have 8-digit filesizes
        line = line.Substring(0, n).TrimEnd();
    }

    parts[0] = line.TrimEnd(); // filename
}
```

Comment: This seems closest; couple of problems: there is a file name '.project' (nothing before extension--it's an Eclipse file). Plus, also this error on: line = line.Substring(0, n).TrimEnd();//error: Lenght cannot be zero.

Comment: I admit that I didn't add any tests here :-) Which line does it fail on?

Comment: line = line.Substring(0, n).TrimEnd();//length cannot be zero

Comment: Sorry, I meant which line from the data file it failed on. I'll add some notes on robustness to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Split on the period instead. That will give you two separate strings: the file and the rest. Split only the second string on space. The very first element of the second string split is your file extension:

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
 {

    string[] parts = line.Split('.');

    string[] secondSplit = parts[1].Split(' ');

    // put together the file path
    string filePath = parts[0] + "." +  secondSplit[0];

    // Do something here with the rest of the second split: secondSplit
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. The value I want are like these:  Console.WriteLine(parts[0] + " " + parts[1] + " " + parts[2] + " " + parts[3]);//will generate file name and path ;// so 4 values?

Comment: I am not sure I understand how that will work for me? I mean, I have to use parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], and parts[3] in subsequent code to populate some excel sheet etc.

Comment: One thing--if there is a space in file name then I can't change that in subsequent code. Is your code trying to remove the space. Anyway, basically, I need 4 values from each line.